# How to prevent html code appearing above pandas tables in quarto gfm reports

Tags: python, pandas, quarto

When I display a pandas table in a quarto gfm report I see html code above the table when I view the report in github. How can I prevent this?

[image]

## Code from Qmd file that created the above report

````
---
title: 'HTML junk'
author: 'Joseph Powers'
date: 2024-03-14
format: gfm
---

```{python}
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

# Notice the html code above the table
```{python}
N = int(5e3)
TRIALS = int(1)

pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "B": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "C": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "D": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.67, N)
    }
)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`print(pd.DataFrame.to_markdown())`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) instead, to print DataFrame in Markdown-friendly format, and use the quarto chunk option `output: asis` to get the raw markdown table without any preprocessing. After rendering the source qmd file, you will see that the generated markdown file doesn't contain any HTML codes this time.

````
---
title: 'HTML junk'
author: 'Joseph Powers'
date: 2024-03-14
format: gfm
---

```{python}
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

# Notice the html code above the table
```{python}
#| output: "asis"
N = int(5e3)
TRIALS = int(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "B": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "C": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "D": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.67, N)
    }
)

print(df.to_markdown())
```
````